# Displaying different <tr> depending on radio button (in Knockout)

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

OK, here goes.

Problem 1: 
I want to, based on the radio button checked, display a tr-element or not. Threre will be 3 buttons, displaying 'unlocked achievements', 'locked', and 'all' (both locked + unlocked).

The code below shows how it looks when I try to call three different functions, each setting the tr:s visibility to true/false depending on radio button checked. (D.R.Y, I know, but right now I'm just looking for the functionality).

Problem 2: 
Making the for-loop run. itemsListForFilter is declared globally, outside the filter function. itemsListForFilter is a copy of an object arrayMap which is initiallized and filled elsewhere in the code. The array contains items  with - amongst other things - the boolean "radioCheck", with the default value "true", which I want to check.

When I access itemsListForFilter in the function where the copying takes place it's filled with items but...
When I try to access itemsListForFilter in the filter function it displays as having the value of null. So the copy is "lost" somewhere :)

View / HTML:

```
<div class="widget-header-container">
                <h3 class="widget-header">Achievements</h3>
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <input type="radio" name="appliedFilter" value="all" data-bind="checked: filterAll"/><label for="all">Show all</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="appliedFilter" value="unlocked" data-bind="checked: filterUnlocked"/><label for="unlocked">Unlocked</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="appliedFilter" value="locked" data-bind="checked: filterLocked"/><label for="locked">Locked</label>
                </div>

                <div><div class="widget-header-line-game1"></div><div class="widget-header-line-game2"></div><div class="widget-header-line-shadow"></div></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="rounded-box" style="padding:15px;padding-top: 0;background-color:#fff;overflow:hidden;">
                    <table id="game-achievements" class="table table-condensed" style="margin-top:10px;">
                        <tbody data-bind="foreach: viewGame.achievements()">
                            <tr data-bind="visible: radioCheck" style="display: none">
```

Viewmodel / JS:

```
filterUnlocked: function(){
    return filter('unlocked');
},
filterLocked: function(){
    return filter('locked');
},
filterAll: function(){
    return filter('all');
},
filter: function(x){

    for (var item in itemsListForFilter){
        if (x === 'locked'){
            item.radioCheck = '!achieved';
        }
        if (x === 'unlocked') {
            item.radioCheck = 'achieved';
        }
        else {item.radioCheck = true;}
    }
```

Observe that the viewmodel is an object and not a function:

```
var gamesViewModel = {

self: this,
settings: null,
gameId: null,
authorized: false,
(...)
```

Right now the functions named filterUnlocked, etc (except filter) displays as "unused properties" in the JS file. What should i do to call them from the HTML? Or is there a better way to accomplish what I'm looking for?

Thank you.

Comment: This is kind of a nonstandard approach to filtering. Are you optimizing to reduce DOM inserts and deletes in the table, or would you be ok with the table redrawing all rows when the filter changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the effect you want with less complexity.

First, the radio group. The `checked` binding in Knockout kind of replaces (or acts like) the name attribute for a radio group: all the radio buttons should share one. The bound variable will be updated to the value of the selected radio button, which will cause others bound to the same variable to de-select. Now you have one variable to look at instead of three.

Instead of doing filtering by hiding rows, it is more usual to have a `computed` filter the data, and the table just displays it. The computed can get the data from "outside"; it doesn't have to be an observable or part of the viewmodel (although if it's not an observable, you'll need to tell the computed when to update, if the source changes).

Here's a little working example:

```js
var achievements = [{
  name: 'The locked one',
  locked: true
}, {
  name: 'The unlocked one',
  locked: false
}];
var vm = {
  appliedFilter: ko.observable('all'),
  viewGame: {}
};

vm.viewGame.achievements = ko.computed(function() {
  var filter = vm.appliedFilter();
  if (filter === 'all') {
    return achievements;
  }
  return ko.utils.arrayFilter(achievements, function(item) {
    return item.locked === (filter === 'locked');
  });
});

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="widget-header-container">
  <h3 class="widget-header">Achievements</h3>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <input type="radio" value="all" data-bind="checked: appliedFilter" />
    <label for="all">Show all</label>
    <input type="radio" value="unlocked" data-bind="checked: appliedFilter" />
    <label for="unlocked">Unlocked</label>
    <input type="radio" value="locked" data-bind="checked: appliedFilter" />
    <label for="locked">Locked</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="rounded-box" style="padding:15px;padding-top: 0;background-color:#fff;overflow:hidden;">
    <table id="game-achievements" class="table table-condensed" style="margin-top:10px;">
      <tbody data-bind="foreach: viewGame.achievements()">
        <tr><td data-bind="text: name"></td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, Roy! 
I was able to solve it in a simpler way than I initially thought.